# catch PIL exceptions in Tornado

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tornado

Catching errors dont works partialy!

What I want to do is to detect if the user uploads real pictures or forged ones *(for example a text file renamed to `.jpeg`)*.

```
try:
    image = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(buf=avat))
    type = image.format
    (x, y) = image.size
    print x, y
    if x < y:
        orientation = "portrait"
    else:
        orientation = "paysage" 
    pref = str(time.time())
    nomf = pref.replace(".", "") 
    nomfich = nomf+"."+type
    self.fs = GridFS(self.db)
    avatar_id = self.fs.put(avat, content_type=avctype, filename=nomfich)
except IOError, TypeError:
    self.redirect("/erreur-im")
```

Here is the taceball shown in `http://localhost:8000/erreur-im`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.3.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1023, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Mon projet\sog-emouk\handlers.py", line 101, in get
    avctype = self.db.users.find_one()["avctype"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here, I wanted to do is redirect users to a page to tell them that the user must use image picture.

and when I've changed `self.redirect` to `self.write("please upload....")` the result was bizarre:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.3.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1023, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Mon projet\sog-emouk\handlers.py", line 153, in post
    user={"pseudo":pseudo, "orientation":orientation, "avctype":avctype, "password":password, "email":email, "tel":tel, "commune":commune, "coord":coord, "statut":statut, "telf":telf, "avatar":avatar_id, "acheteur":[], "vendeur":[]}
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'orientation' referenced before assignment
```

So, I guess that `self.redirect` has something strange here since `self.write` excecutes the code after catching the exception *(indeed the image.size is not known due to text file)*.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This traceback suggests you are redirecting to a code that is again throwing an uncaught exception at both places.
See this : `avctype = self.db.users.find_one()["avctype"]` and

```
user={"pseudo":pseudo, "orientation":orientation, "avctype":avctype, "password":password, "email":email, "tel":tel, "commune":commune, "coord":coord, "statut":statut, "telf":telf, "avatar":avatar_id, "acheteur":[], "vendeur":[]}
```

See both the tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.3.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1023, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Mon projet\sog-emouk\handlers.py", line 101, in get
    avctype = self.db.users.find_one()["avctype"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.3.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1023, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Mon projet\sog-emouk\handlers.py", line 153, in post
    user={"pseudo":pseudo, "orientation":orientation, "avctype":avctype, "password":password, "email":email, "tel":tel, "commune":commune, "coord":coord, "statut":statut, "telf":telf, "avatar":avatar_id, "acheteur":[], "vendeur":[]}
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'orientation' referenced before assignment
```

So I think you have an error in you application where you are initializing your application and request handlers.

In addition you also have a [look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266648/python-check-if-uploaded-file-is-jpg)  how to check whether the file is actually jpeg. In fact you can check for other media file formats avi, rm etc checking the first four characters.

Comment: ah! now i get it, because avctype was declared before, so there is an error to read this! thank you again, and thank you for the link ;)