# How to check if a CSV has a header using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to check if the first row has only strings in it (ie a header). I'm trying to avoid using any extras like pandas etc. I'm thinking I'll use an if statement like if row[0] is a string print this is a CSV but I don't really know how to do that :-S any suggestions?

Comment: That really depends on how you define a 'header'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions everyone, I think  I've found a way to do it.

Comment: @plshelp can you share how you do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4787949/in%c3%aas-martins -

Answer (score 11):

Python has a built in [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) that could help. E.g.

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
    has_header = sniffer.has_header(csvfile.read(2048))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked well for me. But can you please explain why did you pass `2048` but not any other number?

Comment: @AzharKhan `2048` is an entirely arbitrary number. It just needs to be big enough to read in at least two or three CSV rows. You could instead read in a few lines to a string and pass that to `has_header`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: sniffer.has_header always return True... I tested several csv files... :/

Comment: It's working but for a large file, it takes too much time.

Comment: In python3, you might need to change 'rb' to newline='' (python3 gets a lot more specific on bytes vs strings, but changing to 'r' may assume a newline delimiter)

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this:

```
is_header = not any(cell.isdigit() for cell in csv_table[0])
```

Given a CSV table `csv_table`, grab the top (zeroth) row. Iterate through the cells and check if they contain any pure digit strings. If so, it's not a header. Negate that with a `not` in front of the whole expression.

Results:

```
In [1]: not any(cell.isdigit() for cell in ['2','1'])
Out[1]: False

In [2]: not any(cell.isdigit() for cell in ['2','gravy'])
Out[2]: False

In [3]: not any(cell.isdigit() for cell in ['gravy','gravy'])
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I use with pandas in order analyze whether `header` should be set to `'infer'` or `None`:

```
def identify_header(path, n=5, th=0.9):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(path, header='infer', nrows=n)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, nrows=n)
    sim = (df1.dtypes.values == df2.dtypes.values).mean()
    return 'infer' if sim < th else None
```

Based on a small sample, the function checks the similarity of dtypes with and without a header row. If the dtypes match for a certain percentage of columns, it is assumed that there is no header present. I found a threshold of `0.9` to work well for my use cases. This function is also fairly fast as it only reads a small sample of the csv file.

Comment: if the csv files are big. this could be a problem

Comment: @FoggyMindedGreenhorn Why? We don't read the entire file here.

Answer (score 2):

For files that are not necessarily in '.csv' format, this is very useful:

[built-in function in Python to check Header in a Text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670760/built-in-function-in-python-to-check-header-in-a-text-file/15671103#15671103)

```
def check_header(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        first = f.read(1)
        return first not in '.-0123456789'
```

Answer by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert

Post link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15671103/7763184

Answer (score 1):

Simply use try and except ::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
import pandas as pd
try:
   data = pd.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
   print('csv file has header::::::')        
except:
    print('csv file has no header::::::')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i faced exactly the same *problem* with the wrong return of **has_header** for sniffer.has_header and even  made a very simple checker that worked in my case

```
    has_header = ''.join(next(some_csv_reader)).isalpha()
```

I knew that it wasn't perfect but it seemed it was working...and why not it was a simple replace and check if the the result was alpha or not...and then i put it on my def and it failed.... :( and then i saw the "light"
The trouble is not with the **has_header** the trouble was with my code because i wanted to also check the delimiter before i parse the actual .csv ...but all the sniffing has a "cost" as they advance one line at a time in the csv. !!!
So in order to have has_header working as it should you should make sure you have reset everything before using it.
In my case my method is :

```
  def _get_data(self, filename):
        sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
        training_data = ''
        with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(2048))
            training_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=dialect.delimiter)
            csvfile.seek(0)
            has_header=csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(2048))
            #has_header = ''.join(next(training_data)).isalpha()
            csvfile.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to check this is -> simply reading 1st line from file and then match your string instead of any library.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of ChrisD's answer with fallback for empty files:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    try:
        has_headings = csv.Sniffer().has_header(f.read(1024))
    except csv.Error:
        # The file seems to be empty
        has_headings = False
```

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer.has_header