# How has_header() csv.Sniffer package work?

Tags: python, csv

I wanted to find if an Excel file imported through csv.reader() has headers (column names) or not. When I stumbled across this [How to check if a CSV has a header using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193388/how-to-check-if-a-csv-has-a-header-using-python) article. After which, I wanted to know it's working. But couldn't find any lead. Can anyone help?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) link to [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/csv.py). The implementation of that method starts with a comment explaining the algorithm.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to explain better what you are trying to do. Are you trying to read in an `.xlsx` file using a `csv.reader()`, if so, this is not supported. You would need to use a different package, e.g.`openpyxl`