# Checking file header, signature and type

Tags: python, file

I am making a file type checking program (with file signature checking) but, there are so many file signatures, so I can't compare object file with file signature.

Is there any library checking file signatures, or how can I easily make this script? How can I make one function checking file?

- http://forensic-proof.com/archives/300
- [Python: Check if uploaded file is jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266648/python-check-if-uploaded-file-is-jpg)

Code:

```
__author__ = 'jun'

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys

if len(sys.argv) is 1:
    print(sys.stderr, '읽을 파일명을 입력해주세요')
    exit(1)

try:
    IN = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
except IOError:
    print(sys.stderr, '그런 파일이 없거나, 열기에러입니다.')
    exit(1)

offset = 0

def is_jpg(filename):
    data = IN.read(11)
    if data[:4] != '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0': return False
    if data[6:] != 'JFIF\0': return False
    return True


if is_jpg(IN) is True:
    print ('jpg file')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called detecting the mime type.

[This library](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) can do what you want.