# How to get image Type and size when uploading it ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I am using this code to upload image to cloud storage:

```
class uploadImageTOCloudStorage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        image = self.request.get("file")
        gcs_file=gcs.open(GCS_BUCKET_NAME+'testImage.png', 'w')
        gcs_file.write(image.encod('utf-8'))
        gcs_file.close()

        self.response.write("succeed !")
```

and this form to send the image:

```
<form action="http://myappId.appspot.com/test/uploadImage" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="file" value='file'><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```

How could I check the size and type of the image before saving it in cloud storage ?

>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Check if uploaded file is jpg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266648/python-check-if-uploaded-file-is-jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form element, you can use the image data to instantiate an Image object using code like the following:

(pay particular attention to the way the mime-type is extracted and split to detect valid image formats, and the fact that we're using the google.appengine.api.images class Image to extract the dimensions after using the constructor and passing the raw image data)

```
import webapp2
import google.appengine.api.images as images

class Uploader(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        img_stream = self.request.get ('file')
        mimetype = self.request.POST['file'].type
        img_format = mimetype.split('/')[1]

        if (img_format == 'jpeg' or 'jpg' or 'gif' or 'png' or 'bmp' or 'tiff' or 'ico' or 'webp'):
            imageObj = images.Image (img_stream)
            width = imageObj.width
            height = imageObj.height
            self.response.out.write ('<html><body>uploaded image is %s x %s [%s]</body></html>' % (width, height, img_format))
        else:
            self.response.out.write ('not valid format')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but what's the different between self.request.POST['file'] and  self.request.get('file')

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing that out. I ought to explain that: 

If you read the specification for webapp2.RequestHandler, you'll see the self.request object has several methods for accessing request parameters.

.get() will grab by name from any type of request, but the POST array is specifically for POST request data. In addition, .get() will grab as a string, while [the POST array will contain FieldStorage objects in the case of a file upload](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#files).