# django content_type of a image while testing

Tags: python, django, identification, imghdr

I want to get the content type of the image and I am doing

```
image = open(PATH_TO_IMAGE)

print(image.name.content_type)
```

It gives me error saying str object has no attribute content_type

How can I get the content type?

I am doing this in a test and in my view I am getting content_type of image. I can pass the image to the view but its not giving me content typ

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266648/python-check-if-uploaded-file-is-jpg

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but from what I remember you can use the built in `imghdr` module and use `print(imghdr.what(image))` to get the image's format type

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic) library to guess the type of any file.

```
import magic
image_type = magic.from_buffer(image.read(), mime = True)
```

Or

You can use [Imghdr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) as suggested in other answers.

Comment: I just dont want the content_type. I want the image that I want to pass in the library and in library its checking for content_type.. I want a image type that gives content type in my library

Comment: You can assign the content_type variables yourself, by finding it out